# iOS 11 prefersLargeTitles animation not smooth

Tags: ios, preferslargetitles

I have a storyboard for a viewController and set prefersLargeTitles = true.

I have a question：
The prefersLargeTitles drops quickly as I slip the scrollerview. I'm sure it doesn't have the sort of systematic transition effect.

I don't know why it happened,I wonder how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check it just on simulator or on real device as well?

Comment: Thanks，I found this problem occur when I cancel the Safe Area Layout or Translucent.